# Which is better option, using Map or a For loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

Doing some test. I came with a doubt, which option is better, using a `map` or a `for` (based on performance, space, time,etc).

```
map(myfunction,xrange(n))
```

or

```
for element in xrange(n):
    myfunction(element)
```

Thanks.

Comment: map is eligant. it's in function language style and it shrinks complicated code to one line. never mention speed to much when you are using python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've written it, definitely go with the `for` loop.  `map` will create an unnecessary `list` (of all `None` since that is presumably the return value of `myfunction`) on python2.x -- and on python3.x, it won't call your function at all until you actually iterate over the results!

In other words, only use `map` when you actually want results that you are going to iterate over.  Never use it for the side-effects of a function.  For forward compatibility, never assume that `map`'s return value is a `list` -- If you need a `list`, use a list comprehension:

```
[myfunction(e) for e in lst]
```

If you do want an iterable and you are trying to decide between the analogous generator expression and `map` -- it sort of boils down to a matter of preference.  The amount of difference in speed is *almost* always negligible.  I think *most* prefer the generator expression in terms of aesthetics, but some projects (depending on the developers) may still prefer `map`.  Be consistent with the surrounding code...

Comment: It can also be useful to write it in terms of `map` if you're expecting to parallelize an expensive function in the future, as many of those toolboxes will offer a parallel `map` analogue that behaves the same. This can make refactoring a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I think about is

```
for element in list:
    # you can do something to element here
    myfunction(element)
```

And there is no way to do the same thing in `map(myfunction,list)`

And also some side effect consideration.